# How to add hyperlinks to nodes and links in Sankey-Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, spring-mvc, sankey-diagram

I am using [`Sankey` JavaScript library](https://github.com/tamc/Sankey) with `Raphael`.

I want to enable the click event on nodes and links. For instance, on click, I want to call a JavaScript function or call back my controller (*spring mvc-java*)

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far ? If you could provide us with an example code, preferably as a jsFiddle then we can see how it can be solved.

Comment: Hi,. Thanks for the reply. I have not tried anythink for this. I just used Sankey.js and implemented some graphs. This javascript library wont provide any support for click events on it. So i was wondering if anyone have tried something like this